# How to make a form switch dynamically using a type switcher button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have to make a page, where there are 3 forms within it, but only one should be displayed. Also, these forms shouldn't be connected. For example if I would put in some kind of validation within all 3 of the forms, only the one I use should respond to the validation code, the other ones should stay idle untill I switch the form and use it. I have to make this without frameworks, plain, JS or PHP, HTML and CSS.

I have a page where I can switch forms, 1 is displayed, 2 are hidden. However, I made a validation class, and it is validating all 3 forms, since the 2 i'm not using are just hidden, not disabled so this is not working.

Any one know how I sould make these forms, so they would be independent from each other? I mean, how would they go about making this code, not making mine into account. I want to redo it and just add my other stuff on top of it.

Comment: Perhaps show a bit of the code where you hide and validate things?

Comment: It would be too much code. I was wondering if anyone have ideas on how to do it from scratch and I would just add my validation on it.

Comment: That's not really how this works.  If you can't show what you tried, describe in detail what it is supposed to do, what it is actually doing, and what debugging you've already done, then we probably can't/won't help you.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if my deductions are correct on the little information given, here is probably what you are looking for

```js
const 
  Bt_SwitchForm = document.getElementById("Switch-Form"),
  FormX_Count   = 3;

var
  formActiv = 0,
  formX     = {};

function formX_Submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('formX_Submit on =', this.id )
}

document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach( (elm, Item)=>
{
  formX[elm.id] = { 'f' : elm, 'ref': Item }
  elm.onsubmit  = formX_Submit;
});


Bt_SwitchForm.onclick=()=>{
  formActiv = ++formActiv % FormX_Count;
  for(let elm in formX) {
    formX[elm].f.className = formX[elm].ref===formActiv ? '': 'form_Off'
  };
}
```

```css
form {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width  : 200px;
}
form.form_Off { display : none }
button { margin: 10px}
```

```html
<form id="form1" class="">
  <input type="text" id="inputTxt1" value="" placeholder="input form 1" >
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <button type="rest">reset</button>
</form>
<form id="form2" class="form_Off">
  <input type="text" id="inputTxt1" value="" placeholder="input form 2" >
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <button type="rest">reset</button>
</form>
<form id="form3" class="form_Off">
  <input type="text" id="inputTxt3" value="" placeholder="input form 3" >
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <button type="rest">reset</button>
</form>

<button id="Switch-Form">Switch Form</button>
```

I think it is useless for me to explain this code since you seem to live with a strong power of deduction. ;)